# Looking for a decent explanation of the resolver config of HAProxy resolver config and riding out a DNS outage

Tags: dns, haproxy

The default config for the `resolvers` section is

```
  resolve_retries       3
  timeout resolve       1s
  timeout retry         1s
  hold other           30s
  hold refused         30s
  hold nx              30s
  hold timeout         30s
  hold valid           10s
  hold obsolete        30s
```

I'm looking for a config that will allow a HAProxy instance to ride out a DNS outage of, say, 2 minutes.

I *think* that `hold valid 120s` would do that, but I can't make sense of the documentation description (https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/latest/onepage/#5.3.2) about holding statuses etc.

AIUI, `hold valid 120s` will retain a valid DNS response for 2 minutes with this, but continue asking the DNS servers every 1s due to `timeout resolve 1s` - but that doesn't sound right.

I've searched the interwebz but as yet to find a decent explanation anywhere. Can anyone confirm my assertion, please?

These posts seem to imply that this is correct after a bugfix (https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/issues/345), but there is still a lot of confusion out there:
https://discourse.haproxy.org/t/dns-resolver-trying-to-understand-interaction-between-timeout-and-hold/3042/2
https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/issues/573

Answer (score 2):

Kinda disappointed that nobody responded to this, but it may be this would be a better question for superuser.com.

That said, I'll answer as best I can -- and hopefully others will chime in over time to make this a more complete answer because I only *mostly* understand it at this point based on my own experience [and reading](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.0/configuration.html#5.3.2) =] If I'm misunderstanding any of these I hope someone will correct me in the comments and I'll edit the answer.

- `resolve_retries` - If the resolve attempt fails, retry this many times before accepting the failure
- `timeout resolve` - How long to wait on the DNS server response before timing out
- `timeout retry` - How long to wait after a request
- `hold valid` - once you get a valid response, keep using that for *n* seconds
- `hold refused` - If the DNS server refuses the query don't try again for *n* seconds
- `hold nx` - If the DNS server responds "NXDOMAIN" (domain does not exist) don't try again for *n* seconds
- `hold timeout` - If the DNS server request times out don't try it again for *n* seconds
- `hold obsolete` - This one is kinda tricky but potentially very useful in your case. A DNS server may not return all IPs each time, so once it gets an IP that IP is considered valid for up to *n* seconds even if future responses don't return that IP! (e.g. if you query every second and it turns one of three entries, setting this to 30s would probably ensure that all three IPs stay active.
- `hold other` - I haven't been able to figure out what this means for sure -- no documentation anywhere seems to explain it and I've been too lazy to try to dig through haproxy code to find it. My best guess is that this is "if anything else happens with the DNS request not covered by another option, wait *n* seconds before trying again"

Relevant to your specific question, there are a few things to consider:

First, `hold valid` by itself probably will not do what you want, but I think you can get it if you use `hold obsolete` as well. The trick is that if you set `hold valid` to 120s that won't by itself fix the problem because if the DNS server goes down 115 seconds after your request you still have an issue -- but if you also set "hold obsolete" to 120s then I would expect that even though it didn't get those results for 120s it should still use the old ones.

I have not (yet) tried this myself, though, so I could be wrong.